# Delete last character of string (if exists)

Tags: php

I have a string containing some text, the last character might (might) be a slash, which I don't want. How do I remove that, if it exists?

Is this the "correct" way?

```
if(substr($str, -1) == "/") $str = rtrim($str, '/');
```

Comment: the langage you're coding with?

Comment: @Bouaziz:) It's PHP as already tagged such immediately below the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `rtrim` without a condition, it's shorter and probably faster as well. The added `if` is noise and doesn't offer anything.

Comment: And about several symbols? For example I need cut "1." or "2.", etc.

Comment: @user1954544 I'd go with a regex, something like `preg_replace('/^\d+\./', '', $input)`

Answer (score 1):

if you have a string $string try using

```
substr_replace($string ,"",-1);
```

or

```
substr($string, 0, -1);
```

or

```
mb_substr($string, 0, -1);
```

it will remove the last character from $string.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the last character of a url if it is a '/'

```
concat(LEFT(url, LENGTH(url)-1),replace(right(url, 1),'/',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i need to delete severalsymbols like "1." or "2.", etc. Here's code:

```
/**
 * @param string $string
 *
 * @return string
 */
private function cutNumbers($string)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $position = strpos($string, $i . '.');

        if ($position === 0) {
            $string = substr($string, 2);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

PS: I know there is better solution but anyway - hotfix will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtrim` with two parameters (string to be trimmed, character to be removed)

For your case:

```
rtrim($str, '/');
```